# Is possible NSIndexSet to NSEnumerator conversion?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am new in mac development. I upgrade code of framework in Objective c. I change code like this.

```
    NSEnumerator *e = (NSEnumerator *)[oOutlineView selectedRowIndexes];
    NSNumber *cur;

    while ((cur = [e nextObject]))
    {
      CKDirectoryNode *node = [oOutlineView itemAtRow:[cur intValue]];
      [selection addObject:node];
      fullPath = [node path];
    }
```

Where [oOutlineView selectedRowIndexes] gives NSIndexSet Object. I can't run this code because target is framework.  Is this fine? Please help me.

Comment: I know this is poor question but i want answer of this.

Comment: When you're writing a Framework, (IMHO) it's a good idea to make a separate target that builds an application that links against the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this wont work. NSIndexSet is not an enumerator and cannot be used as one. To enumerate one you can use the enumerateIndexesUsingBlock: method or you use firstIndex and indexGreaterThanIndex:

But you have a much bigger problem if you cannot run your code. The first thing you should do is find a way to run it. You should create an unit test target and add tests that run your code and checks if it produces the right results. If you can't do that you at least need to create a regular app target that uses your framework.

Comment: Thanks Sven. Can you explain. because i don't know more about objective c.

Answer (score 2):

My Problem solved by this method.

```
- (void) goThroughIndexSet:(NSIndexSet *) anIndexSet
{
  NSUInteger idx = [anIndexSet firstIndex];

  while (idx != NSNotFound)
  {
      // do work with "idx"
      NSLog (@"The current index is %u", idx);

     // get the next index in the set
     idx = [anIndexSet indexGreaterThanIndex:idx];
  }

  // all done
}
```

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

You don't cast `NSArray` (not `NSDictionrary`, nor `NSIndexSet`, nor `NSIndexPath`) to `NSEnumerator` to iterate them. (Did you used to use .net a lot?)

In most cases (this does not work for `NSIndexSet` and `NSIndexPath` though), you just:

```
for (id object in collection)
{
    // ...
}
```

and the compiler will generate appropriate code for you (even faster than `NSEnumerator`! This operates directly on the collection's internal status.)

And since your target is a framework (i.e. a dynamic library) you have to either

- write a executable, or
- write unit tests

to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not: `NSIndexSet` is not a subclass of `NSEnumerator`. If you want to enumerate the indexes in an index set, see [this Apple documentation page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010165-SW4), and the section "Index Sets and Blocks" just below that.